# is it good style to have submodules with names of builtin libs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

say I am making a lib with the name `utils` and want a `math` sub module.
are there any arguments against *naming* it `utils.math`, and will it cause any errors?

the only thing I can really think of is if users are importing it as follows:

```py
from utils import math
```

then forgetting about it and expecting `math` to be the builtin one.

Comment: It will be confusing to other readers of the code, who also expect `math` to refer to the built-in library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it won't work, but it would make your code harder to understand at a shallow glance and could cause potential errors if both the module that you override and the module that you've overrides it with have a function with the same name for example that does things different or returns different value type for example.